# Worst Case Asymptotic Complexity of Berstein-Vazirani

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-circuit, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

How would one determine the worst-case asymptotic complexity ($\theta$) of a Bernstein-Vazirani circuit encoding the secret 1111?

Answer (score 1):

Given a secret n-bit string $s = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n$ where $s_i \in \{0,1\}$ the worst case scenario for the Oracle (when all your secret bits are non-zero)  is that you will have a circuit depth $n$ of $n$ layers of $CNOT$ gates. This is because at each $s_i \neq 0$, there will be a CNOT gate from the qubit $q_{s_i}$ to the ancilla qubit.

Comment: So it would be $\theta(n^2)$?

Comment: more like $n$. You only have **at most** $n$ CNOT gates...

Comment: So the number of gates is all that matters?

Comment: The circuit complexity basically counts the number of quantum gates from a given gate set to execute a certain unitary operator... here, the number of gates to encode the secret bit string (to encode the Oracle) scales at worst as $O(n)$. With that said, the Bernstein Vazirani algorithm has $O(1)$ run-time complexity since you only need one execution to get the result, given that you have a `'real' quantum computer...

Comment: The complexity for an oracle-based problem simply counts the number of calls to the oracle. It does not count the number of other gates applied.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I said the algorithm is itself require $O(1) $ call.. but it seems like the OP was asking about the circuit complexity rather... At least that how I saw it when I read the question. :)